# Copy a String using dynamic function

Tags: c, string, dynamic, realloc

Im trying to copy a string into another string.
Facing issue on final output. Please refer the expecting output and actual output.

This is for copy a string in between another string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int n1, n2, loc;
    char *p1, *p2, *output;

    printf("Enter size of p1: ");
    scanf("%d", &n1);

    p1 = malloc(n1 * sizeof(char));

    printf("Enter the P1 String: ");
    scanf("%s", p1);

    printf("\nEnter the size of p2: ");
    scanf("%d", &n2);

    p2 = malloc(n2 * sizeof(char));

    printf("Enter the P2 String: ");
    scanf("%s", p2);

    printf("\nEnter the Location to copy: ");
    scanf("%d", &loc);

    output = realloc(p1, sizeof(char) * (n1 + n2));

    for (int i = loc - 1; i <= n1; i++)
        *(output + i + n2) = *(p1 + i);

    for (int i = 0; i < n2; i++)
        *(output + i + loc) = *(p2 + i);

    printf("\nFinal copy is: ");
    printf("%s\n", output);

    free(p1);
    free(p2);
    free(output);

    return 0;
}
```

Expect I&O/P:

```
Size of string: 6
Enter string: google
size of 2nd string: 6
Enter string: amazon
Location to copy: 2
Final copy: goamazonogle
```

Actual I&O/P:

```
Size of string: 6
Enter string: google
size of 2nd string: 6
Enter string: amazon
Location to copy: 2
Final copy: goamazonW //Here W is the unknown value is printing instead of "ogle".
```

Comment: Same error repeating after changing into size 6 @user3121023

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof(char)` is always 1.  You can simplify your code by eliminating it.

Once you know the size of the string you're about to read, there's no way using **scanf**(3) to limit the input it reads to the size of the buffer you allocated.  In general, we don't rely on the input to describe itself accurately.

In your case, even if the description is accurate, the code isn't: scanf promises to terminate the string read by `%s` with a NUL character, so your 6-byte input needs a 7-byte buffer to accommodate that NUL.  That is one  error.

There is a fancy way to get scanf to allocate the string memory for you.  Traditionally, though, you'd use **getline**(3) for that, and **strlen**(3) to find out how much it read.

As one comment points out, **realloc**(3) invalidates its first argument, meaning `p1` can't be relied on after that call.  You really want `output` to be a separate buffer, into which you'll copy data from `p1` and `p2`.

Once you've allocated your output buffer, though, you may be surprised to learn that **sprintf**(3) is your friend.  One call to that function, with `%.*s` constructions to limit string output dynamically, and pointer arithmetic on the inputs, will generate what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct code of copy a string using dynamic method. Refer the point 1 to get more clarity.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int n1, n2, loc;
    char *p1, *p2, *output;

    printf("Enter size of p1: ");
    scanf("%d", &n1);

    p1 = malloc((n1 + 1) * sizeof(char));

    printf("Enter the P1 String: ");
    scanf("%s", p1);

    printf("\nEnter the size of p2: ");
    scanf("%d", &n2);

    p2 = malloc((n2 + 1) * sizeof(char));

    printf("Enter the P2 String: ");
    scanf("%s", p2);

    printf("\nEnter the Location to copy: ");
    scanf("%d", &loc);

    output = malloc((n1 + n2 + 1) * sizeof(char)); //After allocating a memory to both sizes of string along with adding memory for NULL.

    for (int i = 0; i < loc; i++)
        *(output + i) = *(p1 + i);

    for (int i = loc - 1; i <= n1; i++)
        *(output + i + n2) = *(p1 + i);

    for (int i = 0; i < n2; i++)
        *(output + i + loc) = *(p2 + i);

    printf("\nFinal copy is: ");
    printf("%s\n", output);

    free(p1);
    free(p2);
    free(output);

    return 0;
}
```